# How to loop SQL statements?

Tags: java, jsp, loops, jdbc

I am attempting to run a new SQL command for each value in my List. I have the below, whic just repeats the same value again and again for the amount in my list.

Please note that I have to loop the SQL through the amount of values in my array list, and insert each value as the name in the SQL as shown below.

What is the best way to do this as this definately isn't.

```
    int listSize = al.size();

    for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {         
        ResultSet rs1 = name.executeQuery("SELECT sum(hours) FROM PROJECT_TIME WHERE DATE = '"+date+"' AND name = '"+al.listIterator().next()+"'");
        al1.add(rs1.getString(1));
        rs1.close();

    }
    System.out.println(al1);
```

Result:

[70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70]

Expected Result:

[70, 80, 110, 60, 35, 10, 15, 10, 0, 25]

Comment: Can you try the clause as `name in (print the list)` ?

Comment: `al.listIterator().next()` will always be the same element.  You need to get the iterator **outside** the loop then use it's methods to traverse the set.

Comment: @NoobUnChained Sorry, can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: It will always give you a new instance of iterator and the first element pointed by the iterator i.e. always the first element ?

Comment: As an aside, isn't that code at risk of SQL injection attacks?  I hear DB folks referring to a `PreparedStatement` to avoid such things.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I thought If I loop it, the value would go to the next iteration? Also if I am to traverse the iterator outside of the loop how would that work in regards to the dynamic listSize value?

Comment: I asked is it possible for you to use the `IN` clause of SQL and put all the elements of list int it , like `AND name in (element1, element2 ..)` ?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes, risky code. Just want to figure this one out, then will update to PS.

Comment: *"I thought If I loop it, the value would go to the next iteration?"*  There's no accounting for what people think. *"Also if I am to traverse the iterator outside of the loop how would that work in regards to the dynamic listSize value?"*  What is 'dynamic' about it?  Is some other thread adding or removing elements from the list?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Fair comments Andrew. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, I just spoiled your cool '666' rep. by upvoting.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Haha.. Thats probably a good thing. Not a very lucky number. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is in

```
al.listIterator().next()
```

which returns the same value all the time. Hence the query returns the same result set string, that is why your result is `70` all the time.

try this code instead:

```
int listSize = al.size();

for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {         
    ResultSet rs1 = name.executeQuery("SELECT sum(hours) FROM PROJECT_TIME WHERE DATE = '"+date+"' AND name = '"+al.get(i)+"'");
    while(rs1.next()){
        al1.add(rs1.getString(1));
    }
    rs1.close();

}
System.out.println(al1);
```

Comment: Bloody Brilliant. Just what I was after. You really are the 'Code Man' :)

Answer (score 3):

Every time you are creating new Itrator which return same value every time. Try below code

```
int listSize = al.size();

    for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {         
        ResultSet rs1 = name.executeQuery("SELECT sum(hours) FROM PROJECT_TIME WHERE DATE = '"+date+"' AND name = '"+al.get(i)+"'");
        al1.add(rs1.getString(1));
        rs1.close();

    }
    System.out.println(al1);
```

Comment: Gave you an up vote also for same answer. Cheers for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Please use

```
while(rs1.next()){
  System.out.println(rs1.getString(1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that won't work. As you can See I am using an iterator in the SQL which needs to repeat for the number in listSize, which controls my loop.

Comment: List contains names, values that will changes often, hence the loop, otherwise I would just have a simple SQL statement. with a while loop.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is you need do `al.get(i)` and call `rs1.next()` before reading from the result set.  You should also be checking that the call `rs1.next()` returns `true` before trying to read from the result set.

But this overlooks the fact that executing a query in a loop sucks - the performance will be terrible and you're hammering the database.  Each time you call `name.executeQuery` a remote call is being made with all the overheads that entails and you're doing that for each item in the collection you're iterating over.  If there's 1000 items in the collection, that's 1000 remote calls.  Also, using string concatenation to build the query means the database has to calculate the query plan each time the query is executed.

To do this properly you should perform a single query using a prepared statement and then iterate over the result set - 1 remote call - something like:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;

try
{
  preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT sum(hours) FROM project_time WHERE date = ? AND name IN ?");

  preparedStatement.setDate(1, date);
  preparedStatement.setArray(2, connection.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", al.toArray());

  resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

  List<String> hours = new ArrayList<String>();

  while (resultSet.next()) 
  {
    hours.add(resultSet.getString(1));
  }

  System.out.println(hours);
}
finally
{
  if (resultSet != null) resultSet.close();
  if (preparedStatement != null) preparedStatement.close();
}
```

Without knowing what database you're using it's hard to know if the syntax is 100% but you should get the gist.

Comment: Thanks for that. I definately agree I should be using prepearedStatements to reduce load and for security and I will be changing my code to suit.

Answer (score 0):

Setup the for loop like this to use every entry in the list:

```
    for(String name : al) {         
        ResultSet rs1 = name.executeQuery("SELECT sum(hours) FROM PROJECT_TIME WHERE DATE = '"+date+"' AND name = '"+name+"'");
        al1.add(rs1.getString(1));
        rs1.close();

    }
    System.out.println(al1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the for loop with while

```
Interator i = al.listIterator(); 
while(i.hasNext()){ 
    String name = i.next(); 
    ResultSet rs1 = name.executeQuery("SELECT sum(hours) FROM PROJECT_TIME WHERE DATE ="+date+"' AND name = '"+name+"'"); 
    while(rs1.next()){ 
      System.out.println(rs1.getString(1)); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: no i ddn't...earlier post was something different...here i was trying to resolve the iterator issue.

Comment: It looks just the same to me.

Answer (score 0):

When you use iterator for List, it gives you the very first element location in list, and when Iterator.next() is called, Iterator moves to nest element location.

`int listSize = al.size();

```
for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {         
    ResultSet rs1 = name.executeQuery("SELECT sum(hours) FROM PROJECT_TIME WHERE DATE = '"+date+"' AND name = '"+al.get(i)+"'");
    al1.add(rs1.getString(1));
    rs1.close();

}
System.out.println(al1);`
```